# VS code Dlang: can't change build config

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, d

I am giving D a shot with the [VS code extension code-d](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.code-d). Everything works fine, except that I can't switch configuration, arch type or build type. If I try to do any of these things, I receive the following output message in `code-d & serve-d`:

```
{"code":-32602,"data":null,"message":"`params` MUST be an object (named arguments) or array (positional arguments), other types are not allowed by spec"}
```

At this point, I only have a hello world project, as described in the [code-d documentation](https://github.com/Pure-D/code-d/blob/master/docs/building.md). Am I missing something?

Comment: Such should start from https://github.com/Pure-D/code-d/issues

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this. You can use user tasks in vs code. Create user tasks in vs code for each of your build configuration. Then install this extension (https://github.com/actboy168/vscode-tasks). This will pick each of your task and display it in the task bar of vs code. So you only need a mouse click.